# Can you explain me the CSS in the below code

Tags: css, animation, css-position

Could you please explain me the CSS in this code, I mean how horizontal scrolling output came?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 200vw; height: 100vh; overflow-x: scroll">
  <div class="parent" style="width: 200vw; height: 100vw">
    <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 100vw; height: 100vh">Hi</div>
    <div class="child" style="float: right; width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
      Hi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because of `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: It just removes margin on the body.

Comment: @Abin Thaha Why we need to add again an another div width 200vw? And what dose max-width: 200vw do?

Comment: `max-width: 200vw` would set the width maximum available width for the div to be 200% of the window width, why you need a child div with `width: 200vw` is to set the actual width of it to be 200% of the window width.

Comment: I thought overflow-x will results in scroll if the div size is more than the max-width. But in my code, the size is exactly equals to max-width. Then why scroll bar is being displayed?

Comment: Instead of `max-width` if you specify `width` to your parent, there won't be a scroll to the parent, instead the scroll will be on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the below snippet, I have 2 div's.

A parent and a child.

Parent has width **200px**, while child has **300px**, so obviously the child will overflow. So in order to avoid overflowing, we have provided `overflow-x: scroll`

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought overflow-x will results in scroll if the div width is more than the max-width. But in my code, the size is exactly equals to max-width. Then why scroll bar is being displayed?

Comment: Instead of `max-width` if you specify width to your parent, there won't be a scroll to the parent, instead the scroll will be on the window if the width is more than 100vw, otherwise, there won't be a scroll as the child will perfectly fit inside the parent(In case of no extra margin and padding)